# Profile reputation bar plot behaving strangely

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

This is a problem I have had from a while now, but never bothered to post it before.

In the profile, in the reputation tab, there is a graph. There, if you click on the bars, it will show you which post gave you rep on that day. It is half working on mt computer. I can only see about 40% of the reputation I have gained when I click on it.

Better with images than with words:

## Working good:

[image]

## Working bad:

[image]

NOTE: it has nothing to do with the "show removed posts" tick. It does not change anything for the days shown.